# File sharing between Mac OS and Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, mac, rsync

I am pretty new to Ubuntu so please if you can answer to this question explicitly. I have two laptops one is running on MAC OS X 10.8.5 (OS X Mountain Lion) and the other one running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I want to connect the two laptops via terminal such that I will able to share files between the two. A file sharing system like Dropbox is my aim but of course private, meaning to have a folder on both laptops where I can upload files on one laptop and it then appears on the other.

How would one do this? is it even possible? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One project/piece of software you might want to look into is [NitroShare](http://nitroshare.net/downloads).

This project is actually developed by a couple of guys from this site (NathanOsman & Mateo) and it's nice and simple, is cross-platform, and works between platforms without much hassle at all.

Basically, you install the program, launch it, and it sits in the background until you need it.

**Taskbar Menu**:

[image]

**Device Menu:**

[image]

This isn't quite like Dropbox where it automatically syncs, but it is a very useful tool and you can send whole directories at a time.

Comment: Thanks @RPi Awesomeness for the info about this software. I would like to know where are the files are going to be saved? for instance in the case of dropbox they get saved on the dropbox server but this is not what I want I want to have a folder on my both hard drives and host the files myself.

Comment: @Ilia No problem! With NitroShare the files are stored on your local computer and then only get transfered when you tell them to be. When you *do* transfer them, they by default show up on the Desktop, but you can change that to whatever folder you want so long as you have r/w rights.